# Facing issue in small Screen sizes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-edittext

Hii guys here in small screen size i am facing issue in edittext it is not clearly visible but in large screen size it is showing good[This is a large screen image with 6inch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjzGe.jpg)[This is the error once with 5inch screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UN22.jpg)

Here i post a snippet of code where there are no. of tables which i created using linear layout but in small screen sie its getting hide i have tried making the heigth to wrap content but still its not resolving

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark1"
            app:title="Work Details"
            app:titleTextColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Shramanand Tapsil for the Month: "
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/month121"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" "
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_down"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="8.8">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.2"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.6">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="14dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".8"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Quantity"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".9"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Hour Multiplier"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Shramanand Hours"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".7"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.6"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="All 1 Day Paid activities  "
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".8"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:hint="__"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="3"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:textSize="13sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".9"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtHours1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="x 6"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                </LinearLayout>
  <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_button_bg"
                android:text="Next"
                android:textColor="#fff" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting a `wrap_content` height on the horizontal `LinearLayout` of the first row, so that it fits the content, by replacing:

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.2"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4">
```

with

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4">
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you have hard-coded the text size and it is too large.
I recommend this library (https://github.com/intuit/sdp) for setting the size of the text. It will scale your text size based on screen size.